# WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value' with selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

one week ago I created a script for automatic testing. Starting from yesterday I get the issue below?

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12825/devtools/browser/2aa96c44-290f-4732-85d7-15369b2006f5
FSE Refresh                                                           | FAIL |
Parent suite setup failed:
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)
```

Can the issue be related to the recent upgrade of chrome=65.0.3325.181? Any suggestion to fix the issue?.

Thanks
Andrea

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all :

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value' 
(Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181) 
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f)
```

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- Your *Selenium Client* version is unknown to us.
- Your *ChromeDriver* version is **2.33** to us.
- Release notes of *ChromeDriver v2.33* clearly mentions :

> Supports **Chrome v60-62**

- Your *Chrome* version is **65.x**.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* versions.

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to [**ChromeDriver v2.37**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Upgrade *Chrome* version to ***Chrome v64-66*** levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Chrome* base version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Chrome*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: Hello @DebanjanB I have this issue and I have followed your solution, however it doesn't work.
I am running some protractor tests in a real device, but when sending keys, it fails with the error. I have updated chromedriver, however it is using an old one.
 
E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.111)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455517 (2c6d2707d8ea850c862f04ac066724273981e88f),platform=Mac OS X 10.15.5 x86_64)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Protractor, and updating ChromeDriver can be done by running webdriver-manager update to get latest ChromeDriver and this fixed it for me:

```
webdriver-manager update
```

(Basically experienced the same thing as OP and based on answer from DebanjanB realized I may need to update Chromedriver, but Protractor has easy way of doing so)

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue while running e2e test. 
Updating the protractor to the latest version fix the issue for me.

Here is how you can update your protractor.

1. check the latest version of protractor available e.g now its 5.4.1
2. update the package.json file in your project under devDependencies:

   **"protractor": "^5.4.1"**
3. delete all the content inside the node_modules
4. do the npm install again which will install all the latest version.
5. now run your test again after starting the server again.

Hope this you solve the problem.